# How to convert a .img file to a HEVC/h256 file with c++?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, hevc

I'm trying to convert a .img file that I recorded with a camera into a hevc file for streaming. The .img file is really large and uses too much data when streaming so I want to compress it and am trying to figure out how to do that using opencv.

Comment: Opencv is mainly for video processing, if you want to transcode a video, you should take a look at ffmpeg

Comment: Ok, but you need to say what format of data is in the `.img` file!

Comment: @gerum I will take a look at ffmpeg. Any tips on compressing .img to hevc? I have not seen anything else while searching around.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The .img file contains a video that I am trying to compress to hevc.

Comment: What is the **format** of the data please? `.img` is just an extension. Please provide a link describing **what** it is and where it came from. Thank you.

Comment: @jatt  Even if you can not or dont want to tell us how the video was encoded before a command like this will propably convert it: ffmpeg -i  input_ file.img -c:v libx265 out.mp4

Comment: OpenCV is not for _video processing_, it's for _computer vision_. ffmpeg is suitable for video processing, and for video encoding/decoding.

Comment: @gerum when i try to run that command with even a .avi file as the input it says "Unkown encoder ''libx265"'. https://imgur.com/a/GqYZDgn. That's the full error. If I try running it with a .img file, it says invalid data found when processing input. I've tried with multiple .img files so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is a .img file from a camera. I am not sure exactly what you mean but this is what it says the file type is: Raw disk image (application/x-raw-disk-image).

Comment: @jatt That ffmpeg does not know that encoder probably mean that it is not installed or your version is to old to have support for h265, but if it gives you "invalid data" for you img file, your .img seems not to contain a video, and so it can not be encoded as hevc